# Formatting a USB to FAT16 on Moblin or Ubuntu NBR

Tags: usb, format, fat16

Trying to format a USB to FAT16 on Moblin or Ubuntu NBR

Why? 
FAT16 apparently needed while following this tutorial on creating a Parted Magic LiveUSB
http://partedmagic.com/documentation/130-creating-the-liveusb.html

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/ and http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/04/24/how-to-format-and-mount-a-usb-hard-drive-in-linux/ are the best i've found so far - but ubuntu doesn't have `unmount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 16 <device>`

Comment: on moblin: 
i get command not found. 
fdisk also command not found.

Comment: on ubuntu 10 nbr i can't easily reference the device - is there a way to list where the usb is?

Comment: "unable to open /dev/sdb"

Comment: You should probably be formatting the partition, the the whole thing.  After plugging in your USB device and waiting for it to settle, unmount it and then type `dmesg`.  The last lines should show you the partition (ie `/dev/sdb1`) which was mounted.  Format that **as root**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ubuntu NBR and Moblin don't have `unmount` commands with their visual Mac-like interfaces...

1. Ubuntu Netbook Remiz 10 - System >  Admin > Disk Utility. Click unmount. Click Format Drive.
2. do the mkfs suggested above.
3. `sudo mkdosfs -I /dev/sdb`